# Postfix Calculator

Tags: c#, postfix-notation

Making a console application in C sharp to solve expressions in postfix notation by utilizing a stack, such as:

Expression:  43+2*
Answer:  14

What I've done so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = "23+";
        int counter = 0;
        Stack values = new Stack();


        while (counter < input.Length)
        {
            int temp1,
                temp2,
                answer;

            char x = char.Parse(input.Substring(counter, 1));

            if (  );
            else if (x == '+')
            {
                temp1 = (int)values.Pop();
                temp2 = (int)values.Pop();

                values.Push(answer = temp1 + temp2);
            }
            else if (x == '-')
            {
                temp1 = (int)values.Pop();
                temp2 = (int)values.Pop();

                values.Push(answer = temp1 - temp2);
            }
            else if (x == '*')
            {
                temp1 = (int)values.Pop();
                temp2 = (int)values.Pop();

                values.Push(answer = temp1 / temp2);
            }
            else if (x == '/')
            {
                temp1 = (int)values.Pop();
                temp2 = (int)values.Pop();

                values.Push(answer = temp1 * temp2);
            }

            counter++;

        }
        Console.WriteLine(values.Pop());
    }
}
```

For the if statement, what can I use as a condition to check if x is a operand?

Comment: What happens  when you step through the code and audit every stack operation?

Answer (score 1):

Is your example input 2, 3, + (which equals 5), or 23, + (which is invalid input)?  I'm assuming the former.  How, then, would you write two-digit numbers?  Your current approach doesn't seem to support this.  I think you shouldn't be parsing this char-by-char, but split it into the separate components first, perhaps using a regex that recognizes numbers and punctuation.  As a quick example: `Regex.Matches("10 3+", @"(\d+|[\+\-\*/ ])")` splits into `10`, , `3`, and `+`, which can be parsed and understood fairly easily with the code you already have, (spaces should be ignored; they're simply a punctuation I picked to separate numbers so that you can have multi-digit numbers) and [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) (or `double`, which requires a more complicated regex pattern, see [Matching Floating Point Numbers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html) for that pattern) to see if an input is a number.

You should use a [`Stack<int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw.aspx) to avoid casting and make it compile-time safe.

Answer (score 0):

Surely this is wrong:

```
((int)Char.GetNumericValue(x) <= 0 && (int)Char.GetNumericValue(x) >= 0)
```

I think it should be

```
((int)Char.GetNumericValue(x) <= 9 && (int)Char.GetNumericValue(x) >= 0)
```

Comment: That's what's giving me trouble. What should I use as the condition to check if x is a number? Should it be ((int)Char.GetNumericValue(x) <= 0 || (int)Char.GetNumericValue(x) >= 0)?

Answer (score 0):

I really think this is more like a code review but well so be it - first: please **seperate some concerns** - you baked everything into a big messy monster - think about the parts of the problem and put them into seperate methods to start with.

Then: if you cannot solve the hole problem, make it smaller first: Let the user enter some kind of seperator for the parts, or assume for now that he does - space will do just fine.
You can think of how to handle operators without spaces pre/postfixed later.
So try parsing "2 3 +" instead of "23+" or "2 3+" ...
If you do this you can indeed just use `String.Split` to make your life much easier!

As to how you can recognize an operant: very easy - try `Double.TryParse` it will tell you if you passed it a valid number and you don't have to waste your time with parsing the numbers yourself

Instead of using a while in there you should use a for or even better a foreach - heck you can even do this with LINQ and `[Enumerable.Aggregate][1]` and get FUNctional :D

And finally ... don't use this if/then/else mess if a switch does the job ...

Answer (score 0):

You could say that there essentially are *no* operands. Even digits can be thought of as operators that multiply the top of the stack by 10 and add the digit value; accumulating a value over several digits as necessary. Then you just need an operator for seeding this by pushing a zero to the stack (perhaps a space character for that).

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ashleyf/archive/2009/10/23/tinyrpn-calculator.aspx